# if, else if, else stops in the middle of elses

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from ${db_name}_users limit 1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) 
{
    if ($player[$ships_killed] == 1) 
        echo "1";
    else if ($player[$ships_killed] == 2) 
        echo "2";
    else if ($player[$ships_killed] == 3) 
        echo "3";
    else if ($player[$ships_killed] == 4) 
        echo "4";
    else if ($player[$ships_killed] == 5) 
        echo "5";
    else if ($player[$ships_killed] =< 10) 
        echo "10";
    else if ($player[$ships_killed] =< 15) 
        echo "15";
    else if ($player[$ships_killed] =< 20) 
        echo "20";
    else 
        echo "Over Range";    
}
```

I'm having a hard time with the `less than or equal` signs, it doesnt show the proper value. For example, when the field shows "11" it instead echos "Over Range".

My problem is that specific field grows a lot and I cannot cover every single value with an equals case.

The numbered values will eventually be replaced with an image such as `echo "<img src='img/badges/1i.png' />";` therefore I don't want to echo the value directly.

Is there a workaround this?

Comment: `Less than or Equal to` sign is actually `<=`, not `=<`, although the fact that you don't get a parse error says that your version probably works as well - but it's best to do things properly... And it may just be the reason you are having this problem.

Comment: Also, the correct syntax for your `${db_name}` would actually be `{$db_name}` - your version will work, but will throw an `E_NOTICE` because PHP is searching for an undefined constant called `db_name` and will not find one and use a string value of the name. You actually don't need the curly braces at all in that situation, just `$db_name` would do the job. You only need complex syntax for associative arrays, multidimensional arrays, variable variables and chained object properties (feel free to correct me if I have forgotten anything)

Comment: Also, you are doing `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)` but you never use `$row` anywhere - where does `$player` come from? And where does `$ships_killed` come from?

Comment: im not having syntax errors here, my problem is that the script doesnt read all the else if comments all the way to the end but stops midway.

Comment: my apologies, you are asking me a lot of irrelevant questions. the script that i posted works. my problem begins at the if else if remark. all other values are declared previously. my page is over 1500 lines long and i think it would be redundant to paste it all here.

Comment: Can anyone guess what PHP version he might have that seriously *doesn't* fail with a syntax error here? (Just tested it down to PHP3.0)

Comment: @mario OMG I can't believe somebody still has a <4.0 installation, even for legacy testing - some museum somewhere will pay you a lot of money for that ;-)

Comment: @DaveRandom: It's an unhealthy collection habit. But you know the old chinese proverb: If it still compiles, you may sell it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is the `=<` sign, which is wrong. Try using `<=` instead.

Also, instead of using nested if's, you could use a switch statement, maybe with a counter.

```
switch ($player[$ships_killed])
{
    case "1": echo "1";
    ...
}
```

Teslo.

Comment: teslo, that field getts pretty big, thats why i wanted to add a greater or equal. i dont have another field to compare it with though.

Comment: @user631756 FYI, you can still use `>=` with `switch` -  you can do `switch (TRUE) { case $player[$ships_killed] >= 10: // do stuff }` and it will work. Have a look at some of the comments on the [manual page for `switch`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) - they demonstrate just how versatile this structure can be.

Answer (score 7):

Less than equal is written like this `<=`, sir.

Comment: even with the adjusted signs the script still ends at 4. i have tested the script to echo me the value from $player[$ships_killed] and it gives me the correct number according to my $row.

Answer (score 1):

You've switched the `=` and `<` sign, it's supposed to be like this: `<=` or `>=`. For more information: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php .

By the way, I think you'd be better of using a [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement here.

Comment: wherever i place the <=, the script just stops there and echoes me that value instead of the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I *think* you code should be:

```
// I assume you have a DB called '$db_name' and it has a table called 'users'
// If that's not the case, that's probably what it should be
if (!$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_name.users LIMIT 1")) exit('MySQL query error!');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  // Anything in this array, we echo the exact number
  $exactMatches = array(1,2,3,4,5);

  // I assume your actually want to use $row['ships_killed'] to compare,
  // otherwise there is no apparent point to your database query...
  if (in_array($row['ships_killed'],$exactMatches)) {
    // Echo the number and skip to the next row
    // There is only one row at the moment, but your query is so simple
    // that I presume it is not finished
    echo $row['ships_killed'];
    continue;
  }

  // I would have though you want to display the number below the actual number,
  // not the one above it. For example if I have killed 8, you would show 5, not
  // 10 - the code below reflects this

  // If we get this far, there was no exact match
  if ($row['ships_killed'] >= 20) echo "20";
  else if ($row['ships_killed'] >= 15) echo "15";
  else if ($row['ships_killed'] >= 10) echo "10";
  else echo "5";

}
```

Comment: sir, i truly appreciate your effort however you are trying to shape my script to your idea to what the script should be but its not. the above gives me an error. the script in the question if fully functional i just asked for a workaround to the else if else statements not for a complete rewrite. Again, thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

a little more intelligent approach

```
$kills = $player[$ships_killed];

if($kills] < 6) echo $kills;
elseif($kills < 21) echo ceil($kills/5)*5;
else  echo "Over Range";
```

as for your

> the numbered values will eventually be replaced with an image such as echo "" therefore i don't want to echo the value directly.

this statement makes no sense. you can do this part more intelligent way as well, using **a variable** to set proper picture name. You have to learn programming. It is kinda hard to use PHP with no programming skills. However possible.